# Django Match-team-player relationship player select

Tags: django, django-models

I have `Player`, `Team` and `Match` model

A single team can have more than 5 players with substitute players (maybe 8, maybe 10+ players)
However, there must be 5 players in each team in one match.

My question: How can I choose the players in the match (for that team)

I want it like this; A team= 8 players - let's say their names are a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h

a,b,c,d,e play in this match.

B team= 7 players with names as k,l,m,n,o,p

k,l,m,n,o play in this match

```py
class Team(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255,verbose_name="Takım ismi")
    short_name=models.CharField(max_length=25,null=True,blank=True)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=120,unique=True)
    bio=models.TextField()



class Player(models.Model):
    slug=models.SlugField(unique=True,max_length=120)
    team= models.ForeignKey(Team,related_name='player',verbose_name='Team',on_delete=models.PROTECT,null=True,blank=True)...


class Match(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug=models.SlugField(unique=True,max_length=255)
    map=models.ForeignKey('GameMap',null=True,blank=True,related_name='matchmap',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    league=models.ForeignKey('League',blank=True,null=True,on_delete=models.PROTECT,related_name='matchleague')
    team1=models.ForeignKey('Team',related_name='team1')
    team2=models.ForeignKey('Team',related_name='team2')...
```

Comment: my problem still continue. What should you suggest me @snackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You can select teams and players like this

```
match = Match.object.select_related().filter(name="match_name")
first_team = match.team1
sec_team = match.team2

first_players = Player.object.select_related().filter(team=first_team)
sec_players = Player.object.select_related().filter(team=sec_team)
```

but did you forget player name field?

Comment: it have name and some other fields. I just wrote the necessary fields in here.

Comment: bunuda deneyeceğim fakat şöyle bir çözüm buldum class Game(models.Model): isminde soyut class oluşturdum altında class LeagueOfLegendsGame(Game): oluşturuyorum her oyun için lol dota 2 vs. böylelikle her oyun için düzgün alanlarım olmuş oluyor mesela Fortnite turnuvası için takımlı sistem olmayacak class LeagueOfLegendsGame(Game): map alanı foreignkey Csgo(Game): de ise map alanı manytomany çünkü lolde 1 map varken cs go da birden fazla mapta olabiliyor maç aslında böyle yaparak doğru mu yapıyorum bilmiyorum

Comment: daha verimli bir yolu var mı ben de bilmiyorum şu an ama bence de böyle özelleştirmen daha iyi olmuş