# Django model select players to play

Tags: django, django-models

i have `Match` and `Game` table, i want to choose players who will play in this match (bacause a team include more than 5 players. However a match play 5vs5)

```
class Match(models.Model):
name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
slug=models.SlugField(unique=True,max_length=255)
team1=models.ForeignKey('Team',related_name='team1',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
team2=models.ForeignKey('Team',related_name='team2',on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Game(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
match = models.ForeignKey(Match, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
team1players=models.ManyToManyField(match.team1.player.all())
team2players=models.ManyToManyField(match.team1.player.all())
```

Error: `'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'team1'`

Comment: A `ManyToManyField` expects a model to which it can point. Not a `QuerySet`, and furthermore `match` here is a `ForeignKey` at class-level, so that means that `match.team1` makes no sense.

Comment: What should i do @WillemVanOnsem { my previous post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56920161/django-match-team-player-relationship-player-select }

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having `team1players` and `team2players` in your `Game` model, you can add a ForeignKey field called something like `current_game` in your `Player` model and dynamically assign the current `Game` object to each 5 players from a team. Here is an example:

```py
# models.py, Player model
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    # ... other fields ...
    current_game = models.ForeignKey(Game, blank=True, null=True, related_name='current_players')

# ------------------------------------------------

# views.py
game = Game(name='Sample game')
# some operations
player1.current_game = game
player1.save()
game.save()

# You can access for current players in the game in team order like:
current_players_in_game = game.current_players.values('team', 'name').order_by('team')
```

Comment: exactly what I want is to create a match in the match class and I want to select the players who will play in that match. (in django admin panel)

Comment: current_game = models.ForeignKey or ManytoMany ? i player can have 100+ matches

Comment: and i don't understand views.py part

Comment: You can also use ManyToMany if you want to keep track of previous matches. I thought ForeignKey would be better because one player can only play at one game at a time :)

Comment: Don't worry about views.py. I have just used that to show how to add/access your players in a game.